# Sub Query in Where clause when Sub Query returns multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have the following query which works when the sub-query returns one row. However The sub query might return multiple rows. Is it possible to manipulate this query so it work with multiple rows being returned in the sub query?

I realize the best approach here is to use joins, but this is not an option with this inherited DB structure.

```
SELECT * FROM dev.products
WHERE prodid = (SELECT prodid from dev.kit_products where kitid = 2);
```

Comment: Instead of  `=` you can use `IN` operator.

Comment: You should tag your question with the database you are actually using (although it doesn't make a difference in this case).

Comment: MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `IN` would be your best bet

```
SELECT * FROM dev.products
WHERE prodid IN (SELECT prodid from dev.kit_products where kitid = 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `WHERE IN`:

```
SELECT * FROM dev.products
WHERE prodid IN (SELECT prodid from dev.kit_products where kitid = 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `=` you can use `IN` operator.

**Query**

```
SELECT * FROM dev.products
WHERE prodid IN (
    SELECT prodid from dev.kit_products where kitid = 2
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The IN operator allows you to specify multiple values in a WHERE clause.

```
SELECT * FROM dev.products
WHERE prodid IN (SELECT prodid from dev.kit_products where kitid = 2);
```